# CLion ugly fonts

Tags: 14.04, java, fonts, openjdk, clion

I have a problem with Clion fonts. They look really ugly. I tried different methods to fix that:

- [Urshulyak solution](http://urshulyak.com/page/show/2)
- [JetBrains forum solution](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5531047)
- [AskUbuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564358/openjdk-8-oracle-jdk-8-font-patches-for-ubuntu)

I even installed infinality and changed clion.sh java machine to run java-7-openjdk and java-8-openjdk. None of the above solution works. Can anyone help me with that problem?

Comment: Which clion version you were using? Use the solution you provided, it worked for clion version 2016.1.2. But it didn't work for clion version 1.2.1. Maybe it was a bug for old clion version.