# Messed up Netbeans Fonts

Tags: fonts, netbeans

[image]

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, I just installed Netbeans and fonts are half visible. How to fix it?

Comment: Possibly it requires some specific font which is not installed in Ubuntu by default. Maybe ask at their site about it. Or take a chance and install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Ubuntu Gnome's default font Cantarell. Though I like this font, but it's Line Height is a bit higher, which is causing the menu label wrapping.

Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and change the font to something other than Cantarell. You can try Ubuntu font or install `fonts-croscore` package and use *Arimo* font, which is a great substitute of the Arial font.

In General, You can use [this nice openjdk8 patch](https://askubuntu.com/a/565588/61218) for Java applications in Linux to overcome java's classic non-antialiased ugly looks. The problem is this patch only works for OpenJDK8 as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue start happening when I migrate from Unity in Ubuntu to Gnome Shell.

I used the `gnome-tweak-tool` as @Anwar suggested, but instead of changing the font, I just changed the scaling factor from 1 to 0.96 and it got fixed.

[image]